Does the 43,000 troops in the middle east include the national guard?
From the AP talking about USA troop deployments to the middle east

The additional forces would raise the total number of troops in the region to as many as 43,000.

But I've read elsewhere some states like Tennessee are sending the Tennessee National Guard to the middle east too,

NASHVILLE, Tenn. – More than 700 Soldiers from the Tennessee Army National Guard’s 278th Armored Cavalry Regiment are departing Saturday, September 28, on the first leg of a year-long deployment to the Middle East. The Task Force, comprised primarily of Soldiers from the 278th’s 2nd Squadron, will initially deploy to Fort Bliss, Texas, for a few weeks of additional deployment training before flying to Kuwait.

Does the 43,000 number include other non-federal forces in the middle east? Or, not?

Probably yes. The Guard doesn't operate independently abroad.

Why wouldn't it? When they are called up they are part of the military and count as troops.

Whether it does or not, how could that matter, please?

@RobbieGoodwin if it's your position that troop deployment numbers don't matter, I'm not sure what to say. But that's not a question I have to answer. (clearly) If you don't think it matters, move on. The site has 10,000 other questions you may find more favorable.

Sorry, Evan. I was hoping you'd explain how the relative numbers of National Guard, as opposed to regular Army or whatever else, could matter. Can you? If not mine, will you address the Comments from
IVF comes from the tip and Joe W, for instance? The real Question remains, how could it matter whether deployments abroad included Guardsmen as well as Regulars?

It doesn't matter me to me, it matters only if the 43,000 is inclusive of ALL us forces, or if it excludes the national guard and is therefore higher.

Your article refers to Operation Spartan Shield

Operation Spartan Shield (OSS) is a USCENTCOM (United States Central Command) operation in the Middle East. OSS is commanded by United States Army Central and includes units from all service branches.[citation needed] Task Force Spartan is the U.S. Army component of OSS.[citation needed]

A number of units that are, or have rotated in, that operation's roster are indicated to be National Guard.
3666th Support Maintenance Company, 158th Combat Sustainment Support Battalion, 198th Regional Support Group "Desert Demons", Arizona Army National Guard, July 2020 to March 2021.

A Company, 1st Battalion, 157th Infantry Regiment, Colorado Army National Guard, January 2021-November 2021.[8]

35th Combat Aviation Brigade, Missouri Army National Guard, Aug 2012 - Apr 2013.

36th Combat Aviation Brigade, Texas Army National Guard, Apr - Dec 2013.

42d Combat Aviation Brigade, New York Army National Guard, Dec 2013 - Aug 2014

...

Note that the operation is not indicated to be a combat mission ,at least at this time:

Operation Spartan Shield builds partner capacity in the Middle East to promote regional self-reliance and increase security.


FWIW, I read the article as saying that there are 43,000 active duty or activated U.S. military personnel under the direction of the U.S. Central Command in the region, but that only some of them were part of Operation Spartan Shield, while others were simply naval resources that are deployed in the region apart from any particular operation.

@ohwilleke To add to your comment, US Central Command (CENTCOM) Area of Responsibility (AOR) includes the Middle East (including Egypt in Africa), Central Asia and parts of South Asia. Basically Egypt to Kazakhstan to Pakistan and everything in between (not Turkey or India). Their main priorities is to deter Iran, counter terrorism, helping local military/police operations, and air defense of the region. https://www.centcom.mil/ABOUT-US/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Central_Command
